Animation that require teared cloth simulation
English is my second language, please bear with me
I was trying to do an animation but I couldn't figure out the way to make teared cloth sticking into the handle of a sword with some type of simulation to make the cloth move while falling down, like this but the cloths is wrap mostly around the sword handle

generated by AI
animation ref
https://streamable.com/rg4hb2

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

the linked animation shows just the sword. Is the link correct?

yes, I couldn't figure out how to do the cloth thingy so the animation is just only the sword
